# If the archive already exists, prompt for overwriting it

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

For my final homework, I need to create an archive through the shell, I enclose my code (written in the script_1 file):

```
zip -r backup_Daniil_07.06.20.zip ~
```

But it is very important to make sure that if an archive with the same name already exists, the system will ask you to overwrite it (Overwrite the archive or not). The archive creation team itself is already working. But here's how to display the request, I can not understand. The type of the archive is not so important (you can use tar instead of zip, for example, if this helps my problem). I have already covered the entire Internet and can not find the answer to my question.

Comment: So the task is to do this as a shell script or to convince `zip` to ask?

Comment: The task is not concret. And I can make it in different way.

But the topic of Home Work is related to scripting in shell and I think it will be more elegant.

Comment: Any particular shell, e.g. Bash? Now that we have established that this has nothing to do with Ubuntu, I'll remove the tag. I think, btw, the idea of homework is to figure it out yourself. No problem in asking for help whenever you get stuck, but you basically lay out the whole task here and want it done for you. This is typically not well received here. Either way, welcome to Unix.SE. You can use `[[ -e "$FILENAME" ]]` (or `-f` instead of `-e` if you want to limit the check to files) to test for the file to exist. You can use `test -e` ... you can use `read` to prompt.

Comment: This is an extensive homework.

I did everything related to archives and it was with this task that I had a problem.

Therefore, I ask community to help me, because to be honest I don’t even have a clue in which direction to move. I have already tried the standard archive functions and writing different scripts. Nothing has helped so far.

Comment: If you want to do this in the shell, but are still beginning to learn, I would point you to [this section](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) of GreyCat&Lhunath's Bash Guide; it should contain helpful advice. Also, I recommend using [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net), available as standalone tool in many Linux distributions, to check and debug shell scripts. If you still get stuck, feel free to edit you question to include how far you have come, and people will most probably help you overcome the obstacle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, I understand the challenge correctly, but how about

```
  zip=log.txt;[ -e $zip ] && read -p "$zip exists, overwrite? y/N: " reply && [ "$reply" = "y" ] && zip -r $zip ~
```

It's a bunch of commands in bash, that only are executed, if the previous commands are true. Starts with setting the name of the archive to create (zip=...), then:

- Check, if file exists, if yes
- ask, if overwrite,
- check if user answers 'y',
- create archive

Comment: Thank! Your answer turned out to be key in solving my problem.

But I finalized the solution so that it carries out filtering and appears only when the file exists.

`backup=back_up_Daniil_07.06.20.zip ~
if [ ! -e $backup ]
zip -r backup_Daniil_07.06.20.zip ~
else
  zip=log.txt;[ -e $zip ] && read -p "$zip exists, overwrite? y/N: " reply && [ "$reply" = "y" ] && zip -r $zip ~`